# How to get value from new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {} in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Here is my code and in my class I have declared ansResultinThread varible as follows.

```
protected static  String ansResultinThread = "";
```

Whne I try to access to ansResultinThread value after the callServerForResult method is completed. I am not getting the Updated value.

```
public void callServerForResult(String ans, String casCmd) {

    // String ParsedEquation = parseQuestionForSymPy(ans);
    String ParsedEquation = ans;

    final String stringUrl = "http://localhost:40001/" + casCmd + "/"
            + ParsedEquation;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String Result = "";
            try {
                Result = GetServerResult(stringUrl);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            ansResultinThread = Result;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

How to fix this Issue.

Comment: I recommend to use for connections to server/database with `AsyncTask`, only a hint =)

Comment: Hard to say. You are sure that no exception happens? And what is shown when you print `Result` to System.out? Besides: using a static variable this way has a certain smell; you might consider other options ...

Comment: There is no inherit advantage of asynctask. If you dont want to change the UI I dont see why asynctask would be necessary.

Comment: I used AsyncTask but in this case also I was unable to return a value.@T.C

Comment: In the method I was able to get the result but when i use the variable after the method complete i don't have any value in the variable @EddyG.

Comment: If you are unable to return the value, than you did not corrently..

Comment: Your are right . In my case in need that variable value at some other methods. I it is UI Asynctak will work. @@for3st

Comment: OK, then your problem is that you don't understand this: at the point in time when `callServerForResult()` returns ... most likely, your NEW thread is still executing. It takes some time until it will update the static variable! That is the reason why you should be using the Future interface, as pointed out in the answer!

Comment: @for3st AsyncTask is designed for those use cases.. It is always recommended to use it in such situations!

Comment: But in my code I am check like this while (ansResultinThread.isEmpty()) {
       try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       }
      } .@EddyG

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it happens asynchronously, you need to use the Future interface (see here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html , 8. Futures and Callables)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution do not work because `callServerForResult` returns immediately after the thread is started.

Also keep in mind that using a static variable with multiple threads is generally not a good idea.

The simplest solution in my opinion is to use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a `Thread`.

If you want to keep a `Thread`, another solution is to use a callback.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

// Definition of the callback interface
public interface Callback {
    void onResultReceived(String result);
}

public void callServerForResult(String ans, String casCmd, final Callback callback) {

    // String ParsedEquation = parseQuestionForSymPy(ans);
    String ParsedEquation = ans;

    final String stringUrl = "http://localhost:40001/" + casCmd + "/"
            + ParsedEquation;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                final String result = GetServerResult(stringUrl);

                // Use a handler to invoke the callback on the main thread
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        callback.onResultReceived(result);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

// Usage
callServerForResult("...", "...", new Callback() {
    public void onResultReceived(String result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

The `Handler` is necessary if the callback code needs to run on the same thread as the *caller* (usually the main thread)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I was able to do most of it. But when I use this code it is throwing the below error. Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method onResultReceived(String) from the type MathAnswerCorrection.Callback @nicopico

Comment: Sorry one more quick question when assign the result to a variable it is saying that the variable should be final. and if put the variable as final i was unable to access it from out side.                                         callServerForResult(ans, casCmd, new Callback(){
        public void onResultReceived(String result) { 
         ansResultinThread=  result;  
           } 
      }); can you suggest me on this. Thanks for you reply

Comment: @Vinay Indeed `result` should be final, I have modified my answer. For your first error, make sure to use the correct case. By convention `Callback` with a capital C is a class, while `callback` is a variable